# Group by + sum for different thresholds (preferably in a single query)

Tags: sql, sas

Let's say I have a table with 3 columns:

Column A: Client_ID (not unique, can appear in multiple rows)

Column B: Price paid for a product

Column C: Product (type)

```
+---+----+------+---+
|   | A  |  B   | C |
+---+----+------+---+
| 1 | 5  | 1200 | 1 | 
| 2 | 12 | 10   | 1 | 
| 3 | 12 | 15   | 1 | 
| 4 | 12 | 1750 | 2 | 
| 5 | 12 | 1250 | 2 | 
| 6 | 18 | 10   | 1 | 
| 7 | 18 | 1500 | 1 | 
| 8 | 18 | 1050 | 2 |
| 9 | 18 | 1050 | 2 |
+---+----+------+---+
```

I want to get 6 columns:

```
Client_ID | Product | Number_of_transactions | Sum_of_transactions | Number_of_transactions_over_1000 | Sum_of_transactions_over_1000
```

i.e

```
| Client_ID | Product | Nb_tr | Sum_tr | Nb_tr_1000 | Sum_tr_1000 |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+
|         5 |       1 |     1 |   1200 |          1 |        1200 |
|         5 |       2 |     0 |      0 |          0 |           0 |
|        12 |       1 |     2 |     25 |          0 |           0 |
|        12 |       2 |     2 |   3000 |          2 |        3000 |
|        18 |       1 |     2 |   1510 |          1 |        1500 |
|        18 |       2 |     2 |   2100 |          2 |        2100 |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+
```

With Client_ID x Product unique

I think the first part can be achieved with a simple GROUP BY

```
(SELECT ...
SUM(B) as Sum_of_transactions, COUNT(B) as Number_of_transactions 
...
GROUP BY A, C)
```

However, how can I get Number_of_transactions_over_1000 & Sum_of_transactions_over_1000 also? I know that I can obtain them with a separate query (by adding *where B > 1000*) and I can left join the query for Number_of_transactions & Sum_of_transactions with the query for Number_of_transactions_over_1000 & Sum_of_transactions_over_1000 afterwards, but can it be done in a single query (with a single SELECT instructions)?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your data looks like? makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: Input data, output data or both?

Comment: preferably both.

Comment: @draycut - I've edited my question. I hope it is easier to understand now

Comment: Which Database are you using? Postgres?

Comment: I am not sure. I can tell you I use SAS, therefore I use SQL or Proc SQL to do data operations

Comment: @JuanTutrifor Do you want to extrapolate product_type, as i can see in output data
for clientId = 5 and Product_type = 2 there is actually no input data and still your output table shows data.

Comment: @praxnet - Ideally, yes, I want to extrapolate product_type. However, most important is a clean code (a single query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This will not extrapolate product_type, but gives correct results.
Your input data table is named as data_p in following query, change accordingly.
Also see if SAS supports CASE WHEN operation.[Because of no live SAS DB with me, i could not check it on SAS but this SQL is generic enough.]

```
SELECT
  clientId,
  p_type,
  SUM(price) as sum_of_tr,
  COUNT(*) as num_of_tr,
  SUM(CASE WHEN price>1000 THEN price ELSE 0 END) as sum_of_tr_over_1000,
  SUM(CASE WHEN price>1000 THEN 1     ELSE 0 END) as num_of_tr_over_1000 
FROM
  data_p
GROUP BY
  clientId, p_type
ORDER BY
 clientId, p_type
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for conditional aggregation (`CASE WHEN` inside the aggregation function).

```
SELECT
  client_id,
  product,
  count(*) as nb_tr,
  sum(price) as sum_tr,
  count(case when price > 1000 then 1 end) as nb_tr_1000,
  sum(case when price > 1000 then price end) as sum_tr_1000
from purchases
group by client_id, product
order by client_id, product;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output shows you want results for **all** combinations of `Client_ID` x `Product` even when the combination does not exist in the data (i.e. 0 counts).  Such as the case of `5` x `2`

have

```
+---+----+------+---+
|   | A  |  B   | C |
+---+----+------+---+
| 1 | 5  | 1200 | 1 |
```

want

```
| Client_ID | Product | Nb_tr | Sum_tr | Nb_tr_1000 | Sum_tr_1000 |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+
|         5 |       1 |     1 |   1200 |          1 |        1200 |
|         5 |       2 |     0 |      0 |          0 |           0 |
```

So an important interim question is "*where do the distinct values of product come from*?

In a large data set, one ***might*** find all possible `product` over ***all*** `client_id`. But then you might not.

The most certain way to ensure all products is to have a separate table of products, however, a products table cross joined with the original table (grouped by `product_id`) could deliver a result larger than desired.  *In some SAS procedures a separate table of categorical combinations to be processed can specified using the `classdata=` option.*

A second way is think about combinatorial *coverage* in the original table.  I.e. Separately select and cross the distinct values of hierarchical levels exhibited in the original table, i.e. client coverage x product coverage.  In *some* smaller or stratified data sets the full universe of potential clients and products may not be exhibited.

Example (coverage):

```
data have; input 
client_id price product_id ; datalines;
5   1200  1  
12  10    1  
12  15    1  
12  1750  2  
12  1250  2  
18  10    1  
18  1500  1  
18  1050  2 
18  1050  2 
;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select
    clients.client_id
  , products.product_id
  , coalesce(tr_count,0) as tr_count
  , coalesce(tr_sum, 0) as tr_sum
  , coalesce(tr_1000_count, 0) as tr_1000_count
  , coalesce(tr_1000_sum, 0) as tr_1000_sum
  from 
   (select distinct product_id from have) 
   as products
  cross join
   (select distinct client_id from have)
   as clients
  left join 
   (select 
        client_id
      , product_id
      , count(price) as tr_count
      , sum(price) as tr_sum
      , sum(price > 1000) as tr_1000_count
      , sum(case when price>1000 then price else 0 end) as tr_1000_sum
    from
      have
    group by 
      client_id, product_id
   )
   as summary
  on
   clients.client_id = summary.client_id
   and 
   products.product_id = summary.product_id
  ;
```